# How to add integers in from two 2d arrays into a new 2d array with specified length by user?

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops

I am fairly new around here and this year is the first time I am learning c. I have run into a problem concerning 2D arrays and such. The question is: *Write a program that finds the sum of two 2D matrixes.*

I can do this fairly easily but there is a problem I'm running into. For example I'll give the first set of arrays a length of 3x3.

If my first 2D array and the second array has:

- {1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9} (1st array)
- {0,0,0; 0,0,0; 0,0,0} (2nd array)

I am also given a the number of rows and columns by user. (User inputs 3x2) then it should appear like

- {1,2; 3,4; 5,6} (OUTPUT)

but I am getting

- {1,2; 3,5; 6,8}

Another example

- User inputs 2x4 OUTPUT should be {1,2,3,4; 5,6,7,8}

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXROW 3
#define MAXCOL 3

int main() {
    int ray1[MAXROW][MAXCOL], ray2[MAXROW][MAXCOL];
    int r, c;
    printf("Enter the number of ROWS: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("Enter the number of COLUMNS: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    int sumRay[r][c];

    printf("\n");

    printf("Input integers for Array %d.\n", 1);
    arrayIN(ray1);

    printRay(ray1);
    printf("Input integers for Array %d.\n", 2);
    arrayIN(ray2);

    printRay(ray2);
    arraySUM(ray1, ray2, r, c, sumRay);
    printSumRay(r, c, sumRay);

    //printRay(sumRay);
}

void arrayIN(int ray[MAXROW][MAXCOL]) {
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < MAXROW; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < MAXCOL; c++) {
            printf("Enter Number for [ROW:%d COL:%d]: ", r, c);
            scanf("%d", &ray[r][c]);
        }
    }
}

void arraySUM(int ray1[MAXROW][MAXCOL], int ray2[MAXROW][MAXCOL],
              int r, int c, int sumRay[r][c]) {
    int i, j;
    int x, y;
    i = j = 0;
    int sum;
    for (x = 0; x <= r; x++, i++) {
        if (i < MAXROW) {
            for (y = 0; y <= c; y++, j++) {
                if (j < MAXCOL) {
                    sum = ray1[i][j] + ray2[i][j];
                    sumRay[x][y]= sum;
                } else {
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void printSumRay(int r, int c, int sumRay[r][c]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", sumRay[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void printRay(int ray[MAXROW][MAXCOL]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", ray[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I'd expect `<` rather than `<=` in `for(x = 0; x<=r; x++,i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to put function prototypes before `main()`, or at least move the function definitions before `main()`. It is not at all clear to me why you use a VLA for `sumRay[][]`, but arrays of constant dimensions for `ray1[][]` and `ray2[][]`. Unless you have a compelling reason for doing so, it will be better to use VLA's all around.

You should be using the `size_t` type for variables that hold array indices. The `scanf()` and `printf()` statements that handle the `size_t` variables must then be modified to use the `%zu` conversion specifier.

The `arraySum()` function iterates over two pairs of duplicate array indices for reasons which are unclear. The logic here is convoluted and overly complex. The spurious output that you reported can be traced to this function; it is difficult to read and understand, which should be a sign that it needs to be rewritten. And if your intention is to add the input arrays only partially, the name does not reflect this intention. I have simplified this function, tightening the logic and removing the duplications. See the update below for a version that does partial array addition.

The `printSumRay()` function seems superfluous, since the `printRay()` function can do the same work, so I removed it, rewriting `printRay()` to use VLA's and tightening the code. The original code was using the magic number `3` in the controlling expressions of the loops here, instead of taking advantage of `MAXROW` and `MAXCOL`. But, even when not using VLA's, it is better practice to pass the dimensions to any function that will work with an array.

Here is a modified version of the original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void arrayIN(size_t r, size_t c, int ray[r][c]);
void arraySUM(size_t r, size_t c, int ray1[r][c], int ray2[r][c], int sumRay[r][c]);
void printRay(size_t r, size_t c, int ray[r][c]);

int main(void)
{

    size_t r,c;

    printf("Enter the number of ROWS: ");
    scanf("%zu", &r);
    printf("Enter the number of COLUMNS: ");
    scanf("%zu", &c);

    int ray1[r][c], ray2[r][c], sumRay[r][c];

    printf("\n");

    printf("Input integers for Array %d.\n", 1);
    arrayIN(r, c, ray1);
    putchar('\n');

    printRay(r, c, ray1);
    putchar('\n');

    printf("Input integers for Array %d.\n", 2);
    arrayIN(r, c, ray2);
    putchar('\n');

    printRay(r, c, ray2);
    putchar('\n');

    arraySUM(r, c, ray1, ray2, sumRay);
    printRay(r, c, sumRay);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}

void arrayIN(size_t r, size_t c, int ray[r][c])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("Enter Number for [ROW:%zu COL:%zu]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &ray[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void arraySUM(size_t r, size_t c, int ray1[r][c],int ray2[r][c], int sumRay[r][c])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            sumRay[i][j] = ray1[i][j] + ray2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void printRay(size_t r, size_t c, int ray[r][c])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("%8d",ray[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

As a next step, you might add some error-checking to the input code, checking the return values from the calls to `scanf()`. And, as it is, it is awkward to enter the numbers for the arrays, being prompted for each element. You might experiment with ways to improve this.

**Update**

If your true goal is to combine only the initial rows and columns of your arrays, the above code works with only minor modification. You should still use VLAs, but instead of defining the global constants `MAXROW` and `MAXCOL`, define `const size_t maxrow` and `const size_t maxcol` within the body of `main()`. You should be passing these array dimensions to the functions anyway, not relying on global values.

A function has been added, `partArraySUM()`, with a name that more closely captures its purpose. The *only* difference between this function and `arraySUM()` is that the input arrays `ray1[][]` and `ray2[][]` have different dimensions than the array `sumRay[][]` which holds the results. There is no need to keep separate indices for this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void arrayIN(size_t r, size_t c, int ray[r][c]);
void arraySUM(size_t r, size_t c, int ray1[r][c], int ray2[r][c], int sumRay[r][c]);
void partArraySUM(size_t r_sz, size_t c_sz, int ray1[r_sz][c_sz], int ray2[r_sz][c_sz], size_t r, size_t c, int sumRay[r][c]);
void printRay(size_t r, size_t c, int ray[r][c]);

int main(void)
{
    const size_t maxrow = 3;
    const size_t maxcol = 3;
    size_t r,c;

    printf("Enter the number of ROWS: ");
    scanf("%zu", &r);
    printf("Enter the number of COLUMNS: ");
    scanf("%zu", &c);

    int ray1[maxrow][maxcol], ray2[maxrow][maxcol], sumRay[r][c];

    printf("\n");
    printf("Input integers for Array %d.\n", 1);
    arrayIN(maxrow, maxcol, ray1);
    putchar('\n');

    printRay(maxrow, maxcol, ray1);
    putchar('\n');

    printf("Input integers for Array %d.\n", 2);
    arrayIN(maxrow, maxcol, ray2);
    putchar('\n');

    printRay(maxrow, maxcol, ray2);
    putchar('\n');

    partArraySUM(maxrow, maxcol, ray1, ray2, r, c, sumRay);
    printRay(r, c, sumRay);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}

void arrayIN(size_t r, size_t c, int ray[r][c])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("Enter Number for [ROW:%zu COL:%zu]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &ray[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void arraySUM(size_t r, size_t c, int ray1[r][c],int ray2[r][c], int sumRay[r][c])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            sumRay[i][j] = ray1[i][j] + ray2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void partArraySUM(size_t r_sz, size_t c_sz, int ray1[r_sz][c_sz], int ray2[r_sz][c_sz], size_t r, size_t c, int sumRay[r][c])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            sumRay[i][j] = ray1[i][j] + ray2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void printRay(size_t r, size_t c, int ray[r][c])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("%8d",ray[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Sample interaction:

```
Enter the number of ROWS: 2
Enter the number of COLUMNS: 2

Input integers for Array 1.
Enter Number for [ROW:0 COL:0]: 1
Enter Number for [ROW:0 COL:1]: 2
Enter Number for [ROW:0 COL:2]: 3
Enter Number for [ROW:1 COL:0]: 4
Enter Number for [ROW:1 COL:1]: 5
Enter Number for [ROW:1 COL:2]: 6
Enter Number for [ROW:2 COL:0]: 7
Enter Number for [ROW:2 COL:1]: 8
Enter Number for [ROW:2 COL:2]: 9

       1       2       3
       4       5       6
       7       8       9

Input integers for Array 2.
Enter Number for [ROW:0 COL:0]: 1
Enter Number for [ROW:0 COL:1]: 1
Enter Number for [ROW:0 COL:2]: 1
Enter Number for [ROW:1 COL:0]: 1
Enter Number for [ROW:1 COL:1]: 1
Enter Number for [ROW:1 COL:2]: 1
Enter Number for [ROW:2 COL:0]: 1
Enter Number for [ROW:2 COL:1]: 1
Enter Number for [ROW:2 COL:2]: 1

       1       1       1
       1       1       1
       1       1       1

       2       3
       5       6
```

Comment: @CristianG-- I have added an update to my answer with a new function that combines only the initial rows and columns of the input arrays.

Comment: +1 Hi, it looks like I misunderstood the question, the user specified dimension applies to all arrays, which was your first answer. Anyway thanks for the help! Still learning the quirks to C so forgive me haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Just a minor change is needed. In **arraySUM()**, inside the else part you have re initialized

> i=0 and j=0.

But after the re initialization they are incremented. So it will become 1 so while execution it will read **ray[1], not ray[0]**.

Just re initialize them to -1.

> i=-1 and j=-1